# Why does Notepad++ show some (valid?) CSS in black?

Tags: css, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

When I write CSS in Notepad++, the color coding sometimes seems inconsistent. Normally, selectors are shown in light purple but sometimes they are black for 1 or more lines consecutively. I don't see anything wrong with such lines. Why are they black? What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Problem is probably on some earlier declaration as selectors are also black.

Answer (score 3):

i'm not sure why that happened to you!?

but you can add keywords to notepad++ :

1. Setting => Style Configurator ..
2. Select your language and Style.
3. Add your keyword like `color` and etc , separated by **space** :

[image]

Comment: +1 for the beautiful screenshot! ;-) However, the way my CSS looks is of minor concern to me as long as the colors indicate the structure of the code. So what I really want to know is: **what is Notepad++ trying to tell me by showing some sections in black?** I think black usually indicates invalid CSS. So is anything wrong with my code and - if so - what?

Comment: welcome, yes you right, but the `color` keyword is working in my np++, you can also update your np++

Answer (score 1):

Usually, that sort of coloring indicates that the CSS rule immediately preceding the affected one hasn't been closed. Here's an example where I remove the closing brace from a rule in normalize.css, which affects the one that immediately follows in exactly the same way (ignoring the comment and the lack of bold type, of course):

[image]

Presumably then, the reason why the "first" declaration after that selector is affected but the subsequent ones are not is because the semicolon from the first declaration tells the syntax coloring parser to terminate the nonsensical statement which is formed by the selector. But I'm just blindly guessing.

If you're sure that the preceding rule has been closed properly, then the syntax coloring parser may have been confused. Try simply highlighting the rule, deleting it, and undoing; that usually works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since Notepad++ recognizes color of codes based on the language type, you can't able to view multiple languages with color codes in a same file. Even though CSS is a part of web designing, it is still a unique language. If you want to display the CSS codings inside the HTML to color, just change the language type to CSS (*only for temporarily purpose*). But, don't forget to revert the language conversion back to HTML before saving the file.

---

Steps: Language -> C -> CSS